# Accept dynamic keys in proto struct when unmarshalling JSON

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling

My Proto file looks something like this:

```
    message Test {
        Service services = 1;
    }
    
    message Service {
        string command = 1;
        string root = 2;
    }
```

This .proto can support a json like this:

```js
    {
            "services": {   
                "command": "command2",
                "root": "/" 
            },
    }
```

But, I want to manage a json that looks like this:

```js
       {
                "services": {
                        "service1": {
                            "command": "command1",
                            "root": "/"
                        },
                        "service2": {
                            "command": "command2",
                            "root": "/"
                        },
                },
        }
```

So, here all the services will have common structure but the key name will vary (i.e. `"service1"`, `"service2"`)

Now, I want to read the data from test.json and unmarshal it:

```
    var test *Test
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &test)
```

What changes should I do in the `.proto` so that I can unmarshall this json successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proto [map](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps):

```
message Test {
    map<string, Service> services = 1;
}

message Service {
    string command = 1;
    string root = 2;
}
```

The proto map is [compiled](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#map) to `map[K]V` in Go, so `map[string]*Service` in this case, which is the recommended way to model JSON with arbitrary keys.

This will give the following output:

```
services:{key:"service1" value:{command:"command1" root:"/"}} services:{key:"service2" value:{command:"command2" root:"/"}}
```

Example program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "example.com/pb"
    "fmt"
)

const file = `{
            "services": {
                    "service1": {
                        "command": "command1",
                        "root": "/"
                    },
                    "service2": {
                        "command": "command2",
                        "root": "/"
                    }
            }
    }
`


func main() {
    test := &pb.Test{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), test)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```